Navigation to a certain DeepLink does not check for authentication first
I'm trying to implement a way to check if the user is authenticated before navigating to a certain destination.
This works if I place the authentication logic inside the start destination inside my NavHost without using deeplinks.
Now, the problem is when I use a deeplink, because my scheme is something like myApp://goToScreen. The problem is that the app opens and the NavHost resolves the destination and navigates to it, but my viewmodel validation comes after , which I see the ScreenA and then after a second it navigates back to the login flow.
I want to do it always before navigating but I don't want to include this validation in every screen as this will not scale over time.
@Composable
fun NavigationApp(pendingDeepLink: Uri? = null) {
    EqTheme {
        val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
        val viewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()

        pendingDeepLink?.let { deeplink ->
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.isLoggedIn) {
                if (viewModel.isLoggedIn) {
                    navController.navigate(deeplink)
                } else {
                    navController.navigateToSignIn()
                }
            }
        }

       
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = StartupGraphRoutePattern,
            modifier = Modifier.padding()
        ) {

            // Unauthenticated user flow screens
            unauthenticatedGraph(
                navController = navController,
                navigateToHome = {
                    navController.navigateToHome()
                }
            )
            // Authenticated user flow screens
            authenticatedGraph(
                navController = navController,
                navigateToLogin = {
                    navController.navigate(MainScreen.SignIn.route)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to always check in every screen if the user is logged in before navigating with deeplinks ?
My deeplinks are external only, meaning that I'm not using them to navigate inside the app, instead , I'm using them to open the app from the browser or another app.
This video is when I open the deeplink from my terminal in this case

